# Using C, how to I read in specific information from a file and store in multiple locations

Tags: c, file-io, dynamic-arrays, scanf

I'm given a text file containing information about a game world and it's collision data in this format.

```
 Width 5
 Height 5
 10001
 11000
 11100
 11111
 11111
```

To store the data, I'm given

```c
static int BINARY_MAP_WIDTH;
static int BINARY_MAP_HEIGHT;
```

and

```c
static int **MapData; // Dynamic array of map data
```

My FileIO knowldege doesn't go much beyond reading in strings from a file line by line.

So far I have this very roundabout way of reading in just the first two lines.

```c
FILE *Data;

int line = 1; // line number that we're on

Data = fopen(FileName, "rt");

if (!Data)
    return 0;

if (Data)
{
    while (!feof(Data))
    {
        if (line == 1)
            fscanf(Data, "%*[^0-9]%d%n", &BINARY_MAP_WIDTH);

        if (line == 2)
            fscanf(Data, "%*[^0-9]%d%n", &BINARY_MAP_HEIGHT);

        if (line > 2)
            break;

        line++;
    }
}
```

And to be quite honest, I'm not entirely sure why it's working, but I am getting the correct values into the variables.

I know how to set up the dynamic array, at this point my issue is with reading in the correct values. 
I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: This appears to be an assignment, and while we don't have any rule against assignments in general, the usual question is: have you tried hard enough? Having this question answered with a code snippet will probably hinder your learning process.

Comment: [while-feof-file-is-always-wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong). Start by reading the second answer to that question.

Comment: It's an assignment, but not an assignment on FileIO. We went over it briefly the 1st semester and this is a completely different use of it. I'm just trying to understand how fscanf works. Or maybe how I can skip to the 3rd line and start reading in the data from that point. I've looked at various resources online. I'm not asking anybody to write code for me, I just want a sort of a psuedocoded way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple things you need to know about `fscanf`

1. `fscanf` will consume as many bytes as necessary to perform the
   requested conversions and will update the file pointer accordingly.
   The next call to `fscanf` will start at the location in the file
   where the previous `fscanf` ended.
2. `fscanf` returns the number of successful conversions, so you
   should verify that the return value is equal to the number of
   conversions requested.

So here's how I would rewrite the code you have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int mapWidth;
static int mapHeight;

int readFromFile( char *name )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int good = 1;

    if ( (fp = fopen(name, "r")) == NULL )
        return 0;

    if ( fscanf(fp, "%*[^0-9]%d", &mapWidth) != 1 )
        good = 0;
    if ( fscanf(fp, "%*[^0-9]%d", &mapHeight) != 1 )
        good = 0;

    if ( good )
    {
        // the code to read the rest of the file goes here
    }

    fclose( fp );
    return good;
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( readFromFile( "input.txt" ) )
        printf( "%d %d\n", mapWidth, mapHeight );
    else
        printf( "readFromFile failed\n" );
}
```

The next step is to figure out

- how to allocate memory for `MapData` based on the width and height
- how to read the rest of the lines in a loop, e.g. using `fgets` or `fscanf(..."%s"...)`
- how to parse those lines to fill in the `MapData`

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it to do what I want. So basically fscanf() skips all the text, stops on the number (because of the conditions i supplied it) and then continues at that spot on the next call to fscanf()?